@WebMvcTest doesn't see @Value Annotation
I created a single MessageSourceConfig like below:
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.messages.basename}")
    private String[] basenames;

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasenames(basenames);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        return messageSource;
    }
}

and typical controller like TodoController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/todos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {
    private final GetTodosUseCaseHandler getTodosUseCaseHandler;

    @GetMapping("all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<TodoResponseDto>> getAllTodos() {
        List<TodoAggregate> todos = getTodosUseCaseHandler.handle();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(TodoMapper.INSTANCE.aggregateListToTodoResponseDtoList(todos));
    }
}

and finally created a ControllerTest with WebMvcTest:
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TodoController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageSourceConfig.class, TodoController.class},
        initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class TodoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private GetTodosUseCaseHandler getTodosUseCaseHandler;

    @MockBean
    private CreateTodoUseCaseHandler createTodoUseCaseHandler;

    private static final Long TODO_ID_1 = 1L;

    @Test
    void getAllTodos_success() throws Exception {
        List<TodoAggregate> results = List.of(createAggregate());

        when(getTodosUseCaseHandler.handle()).thenReturn(results);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/todos/all"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].id", is(TODO_ID_1.intValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)));

        verify(getTodosUseCaseHandler).handle();
    }
}

While testing my application, when I try to reach messageSource -> basenames param doesn't work properly. basenames return like ${spring.messages.basename} is there any suggestion?
spring.messages.basename=messages

Expexted Output for ${spring.messages.basename} is messages but it was ${spring.messages.basename}

I believe the solution here is to replace your current annotations with @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureMockMvc. With @WebMvcTest you're supposed to provide mocks for dependencies required by the web layer, and I believe it's not possible to mock @Value. BR

@RoarS. thanks for your comment. Yes, @SpringBootTest works but you know that @SpringBootTest is not performant when we compare it with WebMvcTest... And I don't try to mock @Value, I try to include it to context. And I don't believe, it is directly related with @Value, because when I try to reach @Value under test, I can...

I fail to see where the messagesource is being used. You are using mocks for the controller, so if one of those classes is using the messagesource it won't do anything because it is a mock. I also wonder why you are providing your own, as Spring already provides the MessageSource for you anyway.

@M.Deinum thanks for your comment. Actually, I didn't mock it, I included as @ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageSourceConfig.class, TodoController.class})... And I customized it because I need base/core/other projects messages.properties so I need to define with classpath:... but the magic-point is why @Value annotation doesn't work...

@WebMvcTest does not load property sources so @Value doesn't work. use @TestPropertySource(your source)

@AhmadAl-Sanie if you mean this @TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.messages.basename=classpath:common-messages"}), it doesn't work. And @WebMvcTest loads the @Value properties under test, but not on Configuration class.

As I stated I fail to see where it is being used, you are mocking the dependencies for the controller (there are clear @MockBean annotations on there), so if the dependencies use it nothing will happen.

Interesting but @Value doesn't work for this case. Find two different solutions:
Solution 1: (Using environment)
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageSourceConfig {
    private final Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() { 
        String[] basenames = environment.getProperty("spring.messages.basename", String[].class);
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasenames(basenames);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        return messageSource;
    }
}

Solution 2: (Using @ConfigurationProperties)
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(
        prefix = "spring.messages"
    )
    public MessageSourceProperties sourceProperties() {
        return new MessageSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(MessageSourceProperties sourceProperties) { 
        String[] basenames = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(sourceProperties.getBasename()));
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasenames(basenames);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        return messageSource;
    }
}

